# Windows Server 2012 Putty Connection Network error: Connection refused + Not Access to Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, ssh, mysql, putty

I got a Virtual Private Server with Windows Server 2012 Operation System.
Now I want to install and config MySQL and PHP and Apache on my server.
I found a tutorial and tutorial use Putty for installing software.

But when I want to connect with Putty, I get a network error:

```
Connection refused...
```

I saw every page about this problem and all of them are showing a way to fixing this issue from Ubuntu. But I'm not on Ubuntu, I'm on Windows Server and I have no access to the main Ubuntu server. I just have my Windows Server with admin mode.

What can I do about this issue?

Comment: Hello. This is not about Ubuntu. You have almost nothing to do with Windows and PuTTY. You can install OpenSSH Server on Windows to connect PuTTY with it, but while Windows is primary GUI oriented OS, your abilities to install and configure some software via the command line on it will be very limited. You must use RDP (remote desktop connection). Or you can switch to Ubuntu (no matter Desktop or Server) to met the infinite freedom of the opensource software and plenty of how-to manuals on Internet, etc. :)

Comment: @pa4080 thank you dear friend , I Installed OpenSSH and it works well , I'm still have problem with keys but I can figure it out , I'm thinking about Ubuntu but I need to install PHP and mySQL and a C# Server and I heard they can't be use on Ubuntu , Can I ?

Comment: According to the SSH keys, probably you should convert the key generated by OpenSSH to `.ppk` (PuTTY Private Key), here are two references: [Network error: Connection refused putty](https://askubuntu.com/a/899416/566421) and [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/987775/566421).

Comment: According to C#, please look at this article: [Beginning C# in Ubuntu Linux](http://www.lukemay.com/blog/2012/01/31/beginning-c-in-ubuntu-linux/). According to PHP and MySQL (and probably Apache as web server): [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Comment: @pa4080 Thank you so much Dear friend.