# Permission denied (publickey) error right after generating the SSH keys

Tags: ssh

I know this question might have been asked before But I still cannot really find the answer, and the answer in my case should be simple.

So what have I done is in my ECS server I created a new user and gave it `sudo` privilege by assigning it to the sudo group. Then I change some of the sshd_config parameter:

1. change port from 22 to another
2. PermitRootLogin from "yes" to "no"
3. PasswordAuthentication from "yes" to "no"

And then I generate SSH key by `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
and copy it to the authorized_keys by `ssh-copy-id user@ipAddress`

and then I restart the server, ssh login to the server and get the Permission denied (publickey) error.

In the server `/home/user/.ssh` folder lies authorized_keys, `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` three files. But in my local machine `.ssh` folder there is no key file.

So where is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you generated the keypair on the *server*, instead of generating them on the local machine and copying just the public key to the server's keys file.

Comment: I would suggest you to read also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/898771/566421), and maybe the beginning of [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/899416/566421).

Comment: @steeldriver I think so, if I download the key to my local machine would I get this issue sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed instructions how to connect to SSH server can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu)

From your question it is clear that you should do the following:

**How To Create SSH Keys**

SSH keys should be generated on the computer you wish to log in from. This is usually your local computer.

Enter the following into the command line:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Press enter to accept the defaults. Your keys will be created at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

have the following files in the `~/.ssh` directory in the client machine:

```
-rw------- 1 demo demo 1679 Sep  9 23:13 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo demo  396 Sep  9 23:13 id_rsa.pub
```

As you can see, the id_rsa file is readable and writable only to the owner. This is how it should be to keep it secret.

The id_rsa.pub file, however, can be shared and has permissions appropriate for this activity.

On the server side, you should have the public key (not the private key).

Comment: I think what happened was I generate the key pairs in the server instead of in my local machine...should I delete all the key pairs in the server if this is the case? I tried but I still get the error.. maybe I should delete the authorized key file?

Comment: @jindsay - assuming that you still have access to thessh  server - please create new keys on the client, using ssh-keygen, and make sure that both id_rsa files are in the client .ssh folder.  afterwards copy the new id_rsa.pub file to the server. please review the [link in my answer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu)